# Slide left not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

When i am clicking link content goes slide right and come slide left. It didn't work correctly. I've mentioned css, html and jquery contents

jQuery :

```
        $(".ques1").on("click", function () {
            $("#page1").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1200);
            $("#page2").delay(1200).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1200);
        });
```

HTML :

```
 <div class="content" id="page1">
                <ul>
<li><label><input type="radio" name="ques1" class="ques1" value="label1">label1</label></li>
<ul>
        </div>


    <div class="content" id="page2">
            -------
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
    .content{
    background:#0381BC;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:20%;
    padding:30px 20px;
    border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
    width: 25%;
    opacity:0.9;
    }
    #page2{
    display:none;
    }
```

i didn't use ques1 class
 i have included jquery.min.js

Comment: And where is this class ques1 used in your html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line. Hide and show ???

```
 $("#page1").hide(show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1200));
```

Change it to this

```
$("#page1").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1200);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/qKNEw/)**

Hoe you have included jquery UI library also.